# Angular. Why do checkboxes behave weird?

Tags: javascript, angular

Here is an example of this code on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-poincare-jxpv0)

It's better to see it live. Basically what happens is you click on one checkbox, and the other one gets ticked off. I check the data it's changed, it's correctly shown. The [checked] binding should be false, but it is true.

Something probably specific to angular happens here, I can't see what I'm doing wrong, but something apparently.

Duplicating code here:

```
<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
  </h1>

  <div *ngFor="let value of getDays(); let i = index">
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      [checked]="value === 1"
      (change)="setDay($event, i + 1)"
      [id]="'day' + i"
    />
    <label [for]="'day' + i">
      day {{i + 1}}
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

And app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = "CodeSandbox";
  days = {
    day_1: 0,
    day_2: 0,
    day_3: 0,
    day_4: 0,
    day_5: 0,
    day_6: 0,
    day_7: 0
  };

  getDays() {
    return Object.values(this.days);
  }

  setDay(event, index) {
    const newDays = { ...this.days };
    newDays["day_" + index] = Number(event.target.checked);
    this.days = newDays;
    console.log(this.days, "days");
  }
}
```

Comment: This appears to be caused by an off-by-one-error whereby `day_1` is the first element in your Object, but the `index` property in the `ngFor` loop starts at 0.

Comment: @ExplosionPills, well, yes. They do start from day_1. That's how I need it, because reasons. Don't mind that. But when I handle the (change) I do add one to the index

Comment: This seems incredibly elaborate.. is there a reason to do it like this instead of just - for example - use some reactive form controls? Or as another option - why not simply use an actual array of days and loop through those? Or loop through the days object using the keyvalue pipe. Because your working with primitives, it is very possible that change detection isn’t working correctly- which might explain your issue?

Comment: @MikeOne, yes, it does. API, I guess is the reason. But even that aside, like ok, this seems like a weird way to handle it, but still why does it work this way is killing me.

Comment: @MikeOne, Ok, I guess changeDetection is the reason. I changed the code now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a variable and store values of object:

TypeScript:

```
daysArray = Object.values(this.days);
```

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let value of daysArray; let i = index">
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      [checked]="value===1"
      (change)="setDay($event, i + 1)"
      [id]="'day' + i"
    />
    <label [for]="'day' + i">
      day {{i + 1}}
    </label>
    <p>value is {{ value }}</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: I haven't tested it. But I'm think setDay wouldn't work here. I mean if you would  change the daysArray then, so maybe yeah. But my initial purpose was to track the original object and change it. But I guess now I would have to reformat data. I still can't see why the initial code wouldn't work, is calling a method to get the array in angular causes this bug ? Or what.

Comment: @JavidAskerov I've tested and it works. I do not know the exact reason, but I believe it is related with detection strategy. Because when you use method in template, then Angular should evaluate the expression at each and every change detection cycle and update.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I decided to go:

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = "CodeSandbox";
  days = {
    day_1: 0,
    day_2: 0,
    day_3: 0,
    day_4: 0,
    day_5: 0,
    day_6: 0,
    day_7: 0
  };

  daysArr = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.daysArr = this.getDays().map(item => ({
      checked: item
    }));
  }

  getDays() {
    return Object.values(this.days);
  }

  setDay(event, index) {
    this.daysArr[index].checked = Number(event.target.checked);
  }
}
```

HTML file:

```
<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
  </h1>

  <div *ngFor="let item of daysArr; let i = index">
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      [checked]="item.checked === 1"
      (change)="setDay($event, i)"
      [id]="'day' + i"
    />
    <label [for]="'day' + i">
      day {{i + 1}}
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm just going to make an array of objects from the initial object and update that.

Comment: If this works for you - cool! But please note, this can be solved much easier and cleaner. I’m on a phone right now so can’t provide an example at this time unfortunately..

Comment: @MikeOne whenever you can, if you won't forget, I would appreciate your answer